# I've a django app connected with my local postgresdb,I've built a docker image of that project using dockerfile but, when I run i'm getting this error

Tags: python, django, docker

This is my docker file

```
FROM python:3.8.10

# Install required packages
# RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
#     build-base \
#     postgresql-dev \
#     linux-headers \
#     pcre-dev \
#     py-pip \
#     curl \
#     bash \
#     openssl \
#     nginx \
#     libressl-dev \
#     musl-dev \
#     libffi-dev \
#     rsyslog

# Install all python dependency libs
RUN mkdir -p /ds_process_apis
COPY requirements.txt /ds_process_apis
RUN pip install -r /ds_process_apis/requirements.txt

# Copy all source files to the container's working directory
COPY ./ /ds_process_apis/
WORKDIR /ds_process_apis

EXPOSE 8020

CMD ./manage.py migrate --noinput && ./manage.py initadmin && ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn ds_process_apis.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8020 --workers 2 --worker-class sync --threads 6
```

I'm getting this error I'm new to docker
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your local postgres, you need to include `--network=host` to you docker run command.

Comment: docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "--network=localhost": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown. 

Its showing this error

Comment: Please show your docker run command. Use host instead localhost.